# Converting a JsonDocument to its mapped entity

Tags: spring-data-couchbase

I use `CouchbaseRepository` in my project but sometimes I use lower level couchbase sdk methods to retrieve `JsonDocument`. Is there a way I can use `spring-data-couchbase` to convert a `JsonDocument` to lets say a `User`?

This is all done internally in `CouchbaseTemplate` in the method `private <T> T mapToEntity(String id, Document<String> data, Class<T> entityClass)`

But as you can see it's private so I can't call it myself.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a wrapper which uses Jackson to convert the JsonDocument to any object you want.

`mapper.readValue(doc.content().toString(), SomeClass.class);`

The first argument is the JsonDocument, the content method is what contains the actual Json.

Comment: Upvoted you but I was looking for a way to use the same code that `spring-data-couchbase` uses because a new ObjectMapper will not have the configuration that was defined in my couchbase configuration `CouchbaseConfig extends AbstractCouchbaseConfiguration`